# What is the "Basic realm=" in WWW-Authenticate header?

Tags: authentication, http, realm

Could you please explain what `Basic realm=` means in the `WWW-Authenticate` header? Does it indicate some basic type of authentication? Should it be the only one?

In my case, i use the only possible method for authentication: API KEY (with an `API KEY` header). What should the title look like then?

```
"Basic realm=API-KEY"
```

Is it correct in my case?

Comment: Did you check [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate)?

Comment: @Ivar yes, and stil can't understand, if i use the only one required header `API KEY`, is it basic authentication?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your question is. "Basic" means that it uses the [Basic authentication scheme](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7617). `realm` is ["A string describing a protected area"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate#directives) (spec [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7235#section-2.2)). In your case the `API-KEY` is the value of the realm.

Comment: @Ivar but i guess that `API KEY Authentication` is not `Basic authentication scheme`, so, maybe i should use another string?

Comment: If the header is `WWW-Authenticate` and the value starts with `Basic `, then it uses the basic authentication scheme. I'm not sure what you mean by "_API KEY Authentication_".

Comment: @Ivar it means that request should contain header `API-KEY` and it checks with the reference API KEY, if its equal the auth is success, due to lack of experience, I can not understand what type of authentication is this

Comment: A header is something like `WWW-Authenticate`. If you need to use the _header_ `API-KEY`, then you need to use `API-KEY` instead of `WWW-Authenticate` and most likely set the actual API-key as the value of your `API-KEY` header. I don't believe that there is a standardized `API-KEY` header though.